# permanently set txqueuelen in 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04, netplan

In 16.04, I would change the txqueuelen on a network adapter with:

`ifconfig eth0 txqueuelen 10000`

To make it permanent, I'd put that command into /etc/rc.local.

What's the preferred method for this in 18.04?  (e.g. with netplan and without rc.local)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently not supported natively in netplan (just as it is not supported in ifupdown or networkd).  It's better to use `ip link txqueuelen` instead of `ifconfig txqueuelen` because the `ip` command will be available in more configurations than the (deprecated) `ifconfig` command.  Applying this in a udev rule instead of in /etc/rc.local would allow it to take effect as soon as the interface is available - and after any resets - rather than only at the "end" of boot.

Comment: That worked; thank you.  For others that stumble on this, my udev rule is `SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add|change", KERNEL=="eth?" ATTR{mtu}="9000" ATTR{tx_queue_len}="10000"`   Reboot to apply.