# 20.04 increase txqueuelen

Tags: networking, command-line, udev

I'm trying to increase txqueuelen from the default 1000 to 5000

If i run

```
# ip link set enp1s0 txqueuelen 5000
```

It sets it until I reboot.
I've looked at persisting this, and this post suggests using a UDEV rule
[permanently set txqueuelen in 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033299/permanently-set-txqueuelen-in-18-04)

I've created this by doing the following

```
sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/99-persistent-network.rules
```

Its a new blank file, so I pasted

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="change", KERNEL=="enp1s0"  ATTR{tx_queue_len}="5000"
```

After saving and rebooting, this does not seem to get applied, only by using the first command does it work, with means it doesn't survive reboots

Can someone point me in the right direction on this please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `ACTION=="change"` to `ACTION=="change|add"`.  That is what is used in the link you provided.

I tried a quick test and using `ACTION=="change|add"` set the `tx_queue_len` after a reboot but using `ACTION=="change"` did not.

Comment: great thanks, let me try this out

Comment: yes that worked thanks, no rep to upvote sorry